# Evaluate function from a table

Tags: functions

I want to define list of functions and also use them for evaluation.  But this just doesn't work.

For example

```
f=Table[0,{i,3}]
f[[1]]=x^2
f[[2]]=x^3
f[[3]]=f[[1]]*f[[2]]
```

So far, fine, because f[[3]] is in fact x^5.

Let's say I also need value of second function at $x=2$.  However `f[[2]][2]` does not return `8`.

Comment: try: `f[[1]] = #^2 &`(you need a pure function for that, see documentation). Also: check out: `ConstantArray[0, 4]`:) (fwiw: alternatively: `f[[1]] /. x -> 2`, but I wouldnt recommend that)

Comment: @PinguinDirk OK, this is a step forward.  How can I combine two pure functions together, e.g. f=Function[{x},x^2] and then g=f*f, I would like to get g=x^4?

Comment: Not sure I understand (also looking at @bills answer). I try: either explicitly compose like for any "normal function", like `ff = #^2 &` and then `ff[ff[x]]` respectively: `g=ff[ff[#]]&` or use `Composition` explicitly

Comment: @PinguinDirk I've rephrased the question, can you have a second look?

Comment: it has no way of knowing that the function is in `x`. Afaik, you have to either use `Composition` or else `Replace` (a.k.a. `/.`), as shown above. Sorry don't have the time to write full answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written in the comment, the "functions" you define have to way of knowing that they are in `x`. So if you want to stick to your approach and have functions in `x` in the list, all you need to do if you wanted to execute the function is to [`Replace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Replace.html) `x` by the value, like so:

```
f[[3]]/.x->5
```

Simply speaking, this is pretty similar to what a normal function does in Mathematica, see for example at this excellent ressource: [(go to Chapter 1.2.3)](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/download/MathProgrammingIntro.pdf) (thanks to @LeonidShifrin), or see [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DownValues.html).

Alternatively, you could use pure functions, as @zentient describes in his answer. To compose to pure functions, you might want to use `Composition` or explicitly link the functions, like in the following example:

```
ff = {#^2 &, #^3 &, 0, 0};
ff[[3]] = Composition[ff[[1]], ff[[2]]];
ff[[4]] = ff[[1]][ff[[2]][#]] &;
ff
```

> `{#1^2 &, #1^3 &, Composition[#1^2 &, #1^3 &], ff[[1](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/download/MathProgrammingIntro.pdf)][ff[[2]][#1]] &}

And then for example:

```
ff[[1]][2]
ff[[2]][2]
ff[[3]][2]
ff[[4]][2]
```

> `4`
>
> `8`
>
> `64`
>
> `64`

By the way: using some prefix/postfix/@-Notation might help clean up the mess with all the square brackets...

I hope this helps and gets you started!

Comment: I accept the first solution as an answer.  The second solution does not work for my needs. E.g. `ff[[3]] = 2*ff[[1]] + 3*ff[[2]]` and `ff[[3]][2]` wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2):

In `f`, you have not defined a function, you have defined a list. You can work with lists:

```
f = Table[i^2, {i, 4}]
```

so now you can ask:

```
f[[3]]
9
```

Or you can define a real function:

```
g[x_]:=x^2
```

Now you can ask for g[3] and get 9. To form a "list" of functions, you can define them as a function of two variables, for instance:

```
f[1, x_] := x^2;
f[2, x_] := x^3;
f[3, x_] := f[1, x] f[2, x];
```

So for instance:

```
a f[1, x] + b f[2, x]
a x^2 + b x^3
```

If there is a general form, then you can use that to define a complete collection. For example:

```
g[n_, x_] := x^(n + 1)
```

Now you have defined g[n,x] for every n. For example:

```
a g[1, x] + b g[2, x]
a x^2 + b x^3
```

Comment: I want to have list of functions which I want to combine together.  E.g. f[[1]]=x^2, f[[2]]=x^3 and a*f[[1]]+b*f[[2]]=a*x^2+b*x^3

Comment: See if the update comes closer to what you are looking to do.

Comment: +1 This is a nice inventive solution.  However I like PinguinDirk's solution better, as I want to stick to a real list.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create a [`List`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/List.html) of [pure functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html), for example

```
myfunctions = {Sin[#] &, Cos[#] &, #^2 &}
```

Then grab one of your functions, which is a [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html) of that List, and feed it an argument in the usual way

```
myfunctions[[3]][π/6]
```

which produces

> π^2/36

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want:

```
f[1][x_] = x^2
f[2][x_] = x^3
```

> ```
> x^2
> x^3
> ```

```
f[i_][x_] := f[i][x] = f[i - 1][x]*f[i - 2][x]

f[2][x]
```

> ```
> x^3
> ```

```
f[2][2]
```

> ```
> 8
> ```